# Java ssl/tls client-server application throwing error on sending data trough socket

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

First of all thank you for your time. So Im developing a game server I want to use ssl/tls for communication between client socket and server socket. Ive generated self signed certificate using keytool and this tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjrgy/index.html so I have keystore file cer file and certificate is imported in keystore.

Ive used this tutorial to try if its working https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Using_the_Java_Secure_Socket_Extensions and Im running server on localhost 127.0.0.1 on port 6066 client test is launched on same machine in different terminal window the problem is that when Im trying to write data to stream from client and reading it on server server window will throw this error log.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:928)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at Server.models.ClientConnection.run(ClientConnection.java:34)
```

Im new to this topic so I will be glad for pointing me in right direction and for every help you can provide.

Comment: Are both your server and your client using the same keystore and truststore files?

Comment: if there is no specified truststore property in a client then the client uses default cert folder in jre folder ? right ? If its working that way then they should use same files.

Comment: I'd recommend _explicitly_ telling both server and client to use the same keystore and truststore files (using _e.g._ `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=... -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=...`), just to make sure/rule out that as a potential cause of the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Nothing changed in error log

Comment: `certificate_unknown` means that the certificate that was presented was in an unknown format or had unknown features or version. If there is no specified `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` property the client uses the default *truststore* `lib/security/cacerts` in the JRE. No folders.

Comment: @Castiglia I recommend explicitly *against* that. It won't solve this problem or any other. It won't even work.